# Lose data in long strings when transfering values using ranges

Tags: vba, excel

So, I'm working on a project and at one point I copy data from one workbook to another by setting a range on the one workbook and then setting the range on the destination workbook equal to it. This works great in general, but I have one field that under some circumstances has data that is five digit numbers separated by commas. Zip codes essentially, separated by commas and possibly spaces as well. (Although there aren't supposed to be spaces in that data it is very possible that there are.)

So for example the cell being copied will look like this:
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999

and will transfer as this:
1.11112222233333E+44 or
111,112,222,233,333,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

This is obviously not what I want. How do I fix this?

Here is the relevant code. The column that has the problem data is column F of the Service Areas worksheet.

```
Dim MainWB As Workbook
Set MainWB = Workbooks("SATemplate Data Compile.xlsm")
Dim MDSAT As Range

'Setting the range I want to transfer
Set MDSAT = wb.Worksheets("Service Areas").Range("A13:G13", wb.Worksheets("Service Areas").Range("A13:G13").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp))

'Transferring the range values
MainWB.Sheets("SATemplates").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(MDSAT.Rows.count, MDSAT.Columns.count).Cells.Value = MDSAT.Cells.Value
```

Is this a problem with setting the new range equal to the cell values? Would I have to split this up into multiple parts so that a different range will grab the data in column F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (to force as values (text)):

```
With MainWB.Sheets("SATemplates").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(MDSAT.Rows.count, MDSAT.Columns.count)
    .NumberFormat = "@" 'format as text
    .Value = MDSAT.Value
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Format the cells as text not numbers....